# how to add a non-empty df into a list

Tags: r

I have a list `lst1` and a dataframe from another list `lst2[[df]]`.
If I want to append `df`  to `lst1` with the condition !is.null(lst2[[df]]), what should I do?
I would like to know the way if I use `lapply` as well as `append`

For `append`, I think we can do `append(lst1, list(lst2[[df]])`. I am not sure where to add condition.  I also have the doubt on `list(lst2[[df]])` part. Could anyone guide me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the condition in `if` (assuming `df` is an object for the list name)

```
if(!is.null(lst2[[df]])) lst1[[df]] <- lst2[[df]]
```